# How can I use a keyboard shortcut to go to my Dropbox folder

Tags: finder, keyboard

How can I change the Finder keyboard shortcut <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to open my Dropbox folder instead of the Desktop folder.

Comment: I like command-shift-d for desktop, I'm thinking command-shift-x for Dropbox.

Answer (score 4):

System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > select Application Shortcuts in the left column > click the "+" button > Application = Finder, Menu Title = Dropbox, Keyboard Shortcut = whatever you like > click Add

test it out. worked great for me from Finder

Note that this uses the Finder's "Go to > Recent Folders" Submenu. If the Folder isn´t in the List (and there's no way to keep it there), you won't be able to jump to it.

Answer (score 3):

I can get you most of the way there, but I'm going to say straight off that I don't know how to hijack the <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut.  However, if you're willing to settle for a different shortcut...

1. Open Automator
2. Create a new Service
3. Change the service to receive "no input" in "Finder"
4. Drag in the "Get Specified Finder Items" action
5. Add a new path to your Dropbox folder in this action
6. Drag in the "Open Finder Items" action
7. Save as something like "Open Dropbox"

It should look like this:

[image: Open Dropbox Service]

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select "Keyboard"
3. Select "Keyboard Shortcuts"
4. Select "Services"
5. Scroll down to the bottom and select your "Open Dropbox" service
6. Click the "add shortcut" button to specify a new shortcut

I tried to come up with a way to override the shortcut for the Desktop menu item, but I was unable to do so.

So this will get you a hotkey to open your Dropbox folder when you're in the Finder, but it won't be via <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: This is good, for sure, however will it work from any finder window such as when I'm saving a file?

Answer (score 1):

here's a method that I implemented that allowed opening the Dropbox folder from within any application (well, it gets called by a Terminal session from the Finder).

This does not however, automatically switch to the Dropbox folder while in the middle of a application dialog box;  it simply opens up the Dropbox folder in the event you need to look into or open something within the Dropbox folder.  To access the Dropbox folder from an application dialog box, you can drag the Dropbox folder into the "Favorites" section of the application save/open dialog box to access it within one click.

Ok, if you're still interested in a hot-key anyway to access the dropbox folder, 
here's how to do it:

1. Open Automator: Cmd-Spacebar, type in Automator.
2. Select Service, click Choose
3. Modify "Service receives selected [text] in [any application]" to:  "Service receives [no input] in [any application]"
4. Select the action "Run Shell Script" under Utilities, drag it over to the right pane.
5. Change the "cat" command to "open ~/Dropbox".  If your Dropbox folder is located somewhere else, please modify the pah accordingly.
6. Save as "Open Dropbox Folder"
7. Open System Preferences: Cmd-Spacebar, type in System Preferences
8. Navigate to Keyboard -> Shortcuts
9. Scroll down to General
10. Ensure the checkbox for "Open Dropbox Folder" is checked (enabled).
11. Choose the Keystroke combination to open the Dropbox folder.
    NOTE:  If you choose Option-Cmd-D, you may need to disable "Turn Dock Hiding On/Off" in the Launchpad  & Dock section.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php) to run an AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open ((home as text) & "Dropbox")
end tell
```

In Spark, go to File>New Hotkey>AppleScript and set your settings as such:
[image]

(You can also use Spark to run a shell script, but I'd recommend using this method, as a shell script is a bit more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

Lazier-than-creating-an-Automator-service solution:

1) Open "System Preferences / General", under "Recent items", choose anything other than "None".

2) Open "System Prefs / Keyboard / Shortcuts / App Shortcuts", click "+", choose "Application: Finder", enter "Menu Title: Dropbox", and "Keyboard Shortcut: [whatever key combination you like here, I typed <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>]".

3) Open Finder, visit your Dropbox folder. Your folder and its new shortcut are now listed in Finder's menubar under "Go / Recent Folders".

Assuming you visit your Dropbox folder frequently enough, this will work in Finder navigation. It doesn't work within other app's "Save" or "Open" dialogs, unfortunately.